# How do you stop syncing backgrounds on one specific computer?

Tags: windows-10, sync, desktop-customization

On Windows, you have the ability to sync wallpapers. This is generally a rather neat feature, and I like it very much.

I am logged into my Microsoft account at work, and I would like to have a different wallpaper there.

I've looked over the net, and there are plenty of helpful articles that tell me how to disable wallpaper syncing - but that is not my goal. I *want* wallpapers to sync. Just not on this single PC.

Is there a way to override the syncing rules for one PC only, without impacting the others?

Answer (score 4):

1. From Start menu Hit on the Settings symbol in the left side.
2. Now click Accounts.
3. Hit Sync your settings.
4. On Individual sync settings part, turn off the option labeled Theme to stop Windows 10 from syncing your Windows 10 wallpaper across devices.

Comment: Are you sure that this method only effects the current computer - and not the entire account?